# Spacing between footnotes and footnote mark

Tags: spacing, footnotes

The school I attend requires that footnotes be single spaced with a blank line in between. That is easy enough with `\footnotesep`, but the first footnote has to be close to the footnote mark. Not sure how to do this.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\footnotesep\baselineskip

\begin{document}
This is a trial run of setspace for doublespaceing main body text. I also need
a blank line between singlespaced footnotes with the first footnote as close to the footnote marker as possible.\footnote{sample}
This would be great if it will work.\footnote{sample}
\end{document}
```

Tried to add image but won't let new user. Sorry

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a minimal example file that shows what problem(s) remain after you've fiddled with `\footnotesep`.

Comment: Well, a simple hack would be to delay re-defining the `\footnotesep` until after the first footnote is called.  Try putting the redefinition right before your second footnote and see if that works.

Comment: This isn't a very minimal MWE -- indeed, without the bibliography it won't compile. Couldn't you demonstrate your problem with simple `\footnote` commmands? Your question will get more attention if people can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am new to LaTeX. I just cut and pasted the code, didn't even think about the changes I had to make to get historian to sync up with biblatex. I will be more cognizant in future posts. Thanks for the help and guidance. Your post below seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by cheating how the `\footnoterule` works, since it gets placed before any footnote on the page.

```
\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}
```

You may need to play with the exact value to get it to your liking

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

My only hesitation is that I always find footnotes to be a *dark art*, and although this looks OK, someone may tell you it has an unwanted side-effect!

(I'm not sure that my preference wouldn't be simply to remove the rule altogether, then nobody would notice the issue ...)